# Culinary uses for honeycomb?

Tags: culinary-uses, dessert, honey, honeycomb

On a whim, I bought real honeycomb (not the cookie type dessert) from a local shop. I tried eating it plain, but the wax makes it unpleasant and chewy.

What can I do with it?

Comment: it IS wax. why would anyone wanna eat it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The comb, which is beeswax, holds the honey.  Honeycomb is used for decorative desserts, placed on or along side nicely arranged fruit, is used as a spread on toast or bread or crackers and is served with cheese platters.

As a child I loved honeycomb, would pop a hunk in my mouth and chew like gum until all that was left was the wax, and either spit the wax out or swallow it.

You say the wax is unpleasant and chewy.  The wax will remain chewy, the melting point of beeswax is somewhere around 60 C/140 F.  If the wax has a bad flavour, would suggest tossing the whole thing and trying again.

Don't know of any use other than eating it raw.  Was in the US capital a while back eating across from the bar association national headquarters and had an excellent appetizer platter which had bits of meat, cheese, preserved and fresh fruit, olives, different breads and honeycomb; it was very good.

Bottom line is if you eat it plain, you wind up with hunks of wax in your mouth that you have to do something with.  If you eat it with other foods, the wax isn't really noticeable, kind of like eating the rind on cheese; it just gets ate up.

Answer (score 4):

There's a recipe in [Rose's Heavenly Cakes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471781738) for spun sugar. One ingredient is beeswax. The recipe produces a nest of what I would assume is somewhat like cotton candy.

[image]

It's the finishing component for the St. Honoré's Trifle (which, coincidentally, I just finished making, hold the spun sugar).